# Outlook Plugin (C#)

Tags: email, outlook, plugins

I am working on an application which captures the inbound and oubound e-mails for MS Outlook. My plugin seems to be working fine except for one case -- when I directly attach a file to it from Windows explorer (Go to the location of the file, right click it and do "Send To->Mail Recepient").
Whenever I try this the plugin does not seem to realize that it is a Mail Item for outlook.

Is there a workaround for this?

### Thanks

SL

Comment: What are the symptoms?  I've tried the same thing and confirmed (via Outlook Spy) that the type of item is _MailItem and its message class is IPM.Note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outlook doesn't raise the NewInspector event (and probably others) when it's invoked this way.  See the [MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;916656) for details.

However, the Inspectors collection **does** contain the new inspector window.  You may be able to set a timer that polls the Inspectors collection to detect when a new inspector a launched via the "Sent To" menu.